# SVN scripts to automate tasks

Tags: svn, scripting

I am really new to svn. I need something(Scripts/app), which will compare my local copy with repository, copy the modified files into a new folder and then update the local copy.

I dont know actually, where to start. Please help.

Regards
Bibhu

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really sound like the normal SVN usage.  You should update (SVN update) from the source code database and let SVN merge the new changes with your local files (which I assume have some new code).  TortoiseSVN can help you work with SVN.

Comment: I have svn installed and i dont want to open my solution and have a update, if you go to check for modifications and then click on check repository, it will check your local copy with with svn repository and show remote text status as modified for files which have been changed. i want directly those files in another folder. It will be a sort of incremental release.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no standard way to accomplish this.

But you can run the command `svn status myproject` where `myproject` is the folder of your working copy. It will returns information about the files you have modified. This information includes the paths of those modified files so you can parse the paths using a script (or an application) and copy the them to another location.

After that you can delete `myproject` and do a re-checkout using `svn checkout repositorypath myproject` where `repositorypath` is the repository path of your project.

Comment: i dont need the whole code, just need the files which are modified

Comment: I assume you are using Windows. On Windows, you can installed TortoiseSVN as mentioned by Martin. TortoiseSVN is a great subversion tool with intuitive user interface.

Comment: Brian, i know this question is bit weird, i have tortoise svn installed also, but the requirement is that i dont have to open TortoiseSVN or my solution...there has to be a script sort of thing, where the local copy's path will be there. I just need to run that and it will automatically fetch me the modified files in another output folder, and update my local copy folder after that.